# YouTube Auto Caption Option Missing

Tags: youtube

I used to be able to upload a video to YouTube and let it auto caption for me.  Now, it seems that this feature is no longer available as of about a week ago.  I can't find anything on this.  Does anyone have any insight on this?  Perhaps I need to enable something?